# Regular expression for a file that does not have a line that starts with a specific word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search the entire file not just a line.
^((?!MYWORD).)*$ this will search if I understand correct the line does not start with the word "MYWORD" providing "." excludes newlines of course. So I want to check there is no line at all like this on any line in the file.

So if my file contains:

```
xyz
MYWORD is here
123
```

Then I exclude this file.

Note I am typing my regular expression in the Find in Files dialog of NotePad++ (v7.9.1) where I specify a folder so I want to search all files in folder.

[image]

Practical example find files that don't have a "CREATE" clause in .sql files.

I know someone smart will say use an expression that finds the MYWORD you want then you can eliminate these, but you know I want to know if it is possible.

Comment: So is your goal to have a list of _positive_ matches, files which do not start with `MYWORD`, or do you want a list of _negative_ matches, files which do not match?

Comment: Why don't you use the multi-line flag(m)?     /^(?!MYWORD).*/gm

Comment: `^((?!MYWORD).)*$` matches a line doesn't contain `MYWORD` **anywhere**, not just at the start.

Comment: Yes positive matches that do not contain a line starting with "MYWORD". I did try the  /.../gm approach just could not remember the syntax at the time I wrote this post, anyhow I tried it but it return nothing so I thought maybe it ignoring this??!!

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find files that do not contain `CREATE` you could use this pattern in the *Find in Files* tab:

```
(?s)\A(?!.*\bCREATE\b)
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, dot matches a newline
- `\A` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bCREATE\b)` Assert not the word CREATE in the text using word boundaries `\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gm4uu/1)

[image]